# How to terminate Action from ShouldOverrideUrlLoading for Android Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, android-webview

So, I have this webview that pops up upon navigating outside of the app, I then have a routine in the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` routine that checks if the URL it is being directed to contains a `*.pdf` extension. My goal is to then open the default PDF viewer, and close the webview that was currently open. I can get the PDF viewer to show fine, but am having troubles on ways to implement to close the initial webview. Any ideas?

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url) {

        if (url.ToLower().IndexOf(".pdf") > -1) {
            if (browserType == TPIWebView.BrowserType.InApp) {
                intent.SetDataAndType(global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url), "application/pdf");
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                MainActivitySettings.activityContext.StartActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        } 

        return base.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

    }
```

Comment: what is  MainActivitySettings

Comment: Just a static created class containing webview, icon info, activity type and activity context.

Comment: Don't you want to Finish(); the activity?

Comment: I do, I guess I'm more having issues with trying to access this routine, but can't seem to navigate to it in the correct fashion.

Comment: @dlimes ,  be careful  , that approach is never a good idea as it can cause memory leaks  . to Answer your Question    MainActivitySettings.activityContext.Finish()     will do the job

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed - Thank you, was looking at the wrong item, Had to look directly for the Action. Thank you again!